# Area of a circle segment on sphere, given radius (meters) and central angle (degrees)

Tags: geometry, circles, area, spherical-geometry

### Situation

I have a circle segment and some information about the circle it belongs to.

Given Information:

- **radius** of the circle in meters
- **central angle** in degrees
- lat/long of all three points on the image below.

I need to calculate the **`area`** of the circle segment on sphere. It should depend on the radius of the Earth *(like [great-circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance))*.

### Problem

I have no idea how to do that and couldn't find any algorithms.

Thanks for help

[image]

Comment: What "radius of circle" do you mean: the real ("planar") or the spherical one (measured along the surface)?

Comment: What exactly do you call a "circle segment on sphere" ? Your figure seems to mean a spherical cap, but this is unsure.

Comment: @user I have a spherical one (I measure it using Haversine formula)

Comment: @YvesDaoust So, I have a map (Google Maps API) and I just draw a circle on it [this way](https://i.imgur.com/S0m1V9c.png). And then I'm trying to find out the area of a circle segment

Comment: @MaxMikhalchuk: I am not sure that the curvature of the Earth matters for this size.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Compute first [the area of a full circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832110/area-of-a-circle-on-sphere), then scale the result by $\theta/(2\pi)$ to get the area of the sector corresponding to central angle $\theta$. Finally, subtract from that [the area of spherical triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/area-of-a-spherical-triangle) $XYZ$.